# how to pass an object from one main method to a main method in another class

Tags: java, object, arraylist, parameter-passing

I have two classes `sum` and `f`, and want to use an `ArrayList` (`ac`) from `sum` main method in `f` main method.

### class `sum`

```
package pack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

class sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList < String > ac = new ArrayList < String > ();
        ac.add("hai");
        ac.add("hw");
        ac.add("ai");
        ac.add("hi");
        ac.add("hai");
        Iterator it = ac.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

### class `f`

```
package pack;

import java.util.ArrayList;    
import pack.sum;

public class f extends sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        //here is use the ac object of array list
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only have one main method. You will need a new instance of the other class. `new ExampleClass(param1, param2)`

Comment: You don't need to two `main` methods.

Comment: will u please elaborate @KlemensMorbe

Comment: You can call `main` method of another class if it is `public` which is the case with conventional `main` method which is used as an entry point for Java applications. But the standard `main` method does have a fixed signature. You can change it to your desired signature and call it, but anyway it's not wise, as you can choose another more semantic name for your method to distinguish it from the entry point and avoid confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Sum` class a little bit

```
 class Sum {

        public ArraryList<String> main() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ArrayList<String> ac= new ArrayList<String>();
                ac.add("hai");
                ac.add("hw");
                ac.add("ai"); 
                ac.add("hi"); 
                ac.add("hai");
                Iterator it=ac.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()) 
                {    
                    System.out.println(it.next()); 
                 }

                  return ac;
               }

    }
```

Now change your `f` class like this

```
public class f extends sum {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


     ArrayList<String> ac = new Sum().main();
   // now you can use ac
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two main class, you can add one method in sum class to add arrayList logic as below :

```
class sum {

     public ArrayList<String> getList()
     {
            ArrayList<String> ac= new ArrayList<String>();
            ac.add("hai");
            ac.add("hw");
            ac.add("ai"); 
            ac.add("hi"); 
            ac.add("hai");
            Iterator it=ac.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) 
            {    
                System.out.println(it.next());  }
           }
     return ac;

}
```

And in the **f** class just create the object and call the method:

```
Sum obj = new Sum();
ArrayList<String> list = obj.getList();
```